# Reduce length of URLs in Liferay

Tags: url, liferay, liferay-6, portal

Is there a way to reduce the URL's length in Liferay? IE only allows a maximum length of 2,083 but when I have a lot of parameters to pass between JSPs this causes a problem as each parameter has projectname_WAR_portletname_id in front of it.

I use tinyurl's wherever possible but when I dynamically create a URL using Liferay tags I cannot do that.

The only thing I could think of is to shorten the name of the portlet. I have done this but it is still not enough.

Saving these parameters in the session is not an option as there are a lot of them, say when carrying out an advanced search, and performance is my number one priority

Thanks

Comment: you can add friendly url to your portlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay provides this feature, and it is not very difficult to configure. Checkout http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/portlet-friendly-url-mapping-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-03-en page for details.